# How to add authenticated user object into session using passportjs

Tags: node.js, session, authentication, express, passport.js

I am getting the user authenticated using PassportJS, and it works alright. 
I wanted to restrict its access level so I gave [mongoose-role](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongoose-role) a try.

Following is my user schema with `mongoose-role` module:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
   ip: String,
   local: {
           email: String,
           password     : String
   },
   name: String ,
   created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
}).plugin(require('mongoose-role'), {
  roles: ['public', 'user', 'admin'],
  accessLevels: {
    'public': ['public', 'user', 'admin'],
    'anon': ['public'],
    'user': ['user', 'admin'],
    'admin': ['admin']
  }
});
```

I am using the following code for user signin with the `local` strategy:

```
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'password',
        passReqToCallback : true 
    },
    function(req, email, password, done) { 
        User.findOne({ 'local.email' :  email }, function(err, user) {

            if (err)
                return done(err);

            if (!user)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.')); 

            if (!user.validPassword(password))
                return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Wrong password.'));
            return done(null, user);
        });
    }));
```

Then I have the following route for handling user `signin` and display of its profile if authenticated successfully:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/profile',
    failureRedirect: '/login', 
    failureFlash: true 
}));

app.get('/profile', [ hasAccess('admin'), function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('profile', {
        user: req.user 
    });
}]);
```

Anf finally I have the following middle checking whether a user has permission to access a particular level:

```
function hasAccess(accessLevel) {
    return function (req, res, next) {

        console.log(req.session.user); // gives 'undefined'

        if (req.session.user && req.session.user.hasAccess(accessLevel)) {
            return next();
        }
        return res.json({
            success: false,
            error: 'Unauthorized'
        });
    }
}
```

But `console.log(req.session.user);` gives me undefined. Is this how it should be? Should I not get a `session` object from a `req` object? If yes, then what should I do to have my user after authentication added to a session object so I could access that in on any tab of a given browser?

I have the following middlewares in my app:

```
app.use(favicon());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));    
app.use(session({ secret: "adshlqr3kqwefsadjklqrwefdsbzcjxcq4rewfadshj" }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash()); 
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Could somebody help me resolve this issue?

Comment: try just `req.user` instead of `req.session.user`

Comment: @laggingreflex: Get a `TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasAccess' of undefined` when I try `req.session.user && req.session.user.hasAccess(accessLevel)`.

Comment: which means `req.session.user` doesn't exist. Passport adds the `user` in `req`, not in `req.session`. Try `req.user && req.user.hasAccess(accessLevel)`

Comment: @laggingreflex: Sorry laggingreflex, it was a typo, I had got `TypeError: Cannot call method 'hasAccess' of undefined` error with  `req.user && req.user.hasAccess(accessLevel)` itself.

Comment: That means `req.user` itself doesn't exist (it is the undefined). Passport must not have successfully authenticated or deserialized the user.

Comment: @laggingreflex: But the `if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
                console.log('req.isAuthenticated() is ' + req.isAuthenticated());
            }` gave me a `req.isAuthenticated() is true` on the console, in the `hasAccess` method, before the `req.user && req.user.hasAccess(accessLevel)` check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63267/discussion-between-laggingreflex-and-skip).